# Jest test .toBeInstanceOf(Error) fails

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have trouble checking whether promise rejects with error in Jest test.

(post Jest 20 version:)

```
  test("Rejects on error", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return expect(promiseHttpsGet(null)).rejects.toBeInstanceOf(Error);
  });
```

(pre Jest 20 version)

```
  test("Rejects on error", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return promiseHttpsGet(null).catch((err) => {
      expect(err).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
    });
  });
```

I have tried both versions but Jest test fails with:

```
Expected value to be an instance of:
  "Error"
Received:
  [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443]
Constructor:
  "Error"
```

And the promise returning function is:

```
function promiseHttpsGet(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https
      .get(url, (response) => {
        let responseBody = "";
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
          reject(response.statusCode);
        }
        response.setEncoding = "utf8";
        response.on("data", (data) => {
          responseBody += data;
        });
        response.on("end", () => {
          resolve(responseBody);
        });
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Any leads how to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you've solved this by now, but at a minimum you need to set up your tests to be asynchronous. Did you need an example of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Jest 23 onwards `toThrow` matcher can be used for promise returning functions.

```
  test("Rejects on error", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return expect(promiseHttpsGet(null)).rejects.toThrow(Error);
  });
```

Or the async/await version:

```
  test("Throws on error", async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    await expect(promiseHttpsGet(null)).rejects.toThrow(Error);
  });
```

Comment: Same problem, obviously. 
`    Expected constructor: Error
    Received constructor: Error
`
Why upvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Standard jest idiocy, see: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2549 for explanation. TL;DR Jest globals differ from Node globals and thus jest `Error` != node `Error`